# Perl regex: how do I combine these 2 regex statements?

Tags: regex, perl, selector

I am trying to write a selector which filters out/deletes everything after a comment (#) symbol, but ignores # symbols within strings ("" or '')

So in the below example only the last line would be filtered/deleted

```
"#dummy comment" asd asd
' abc # dummy comment'
abc #real comment
```

These are the two regex selectors I have come up with so far(i will add the s/ tag later on):

```
/('|").*#.*('|")/g        --> selects fake commnts

/#(?!!).+/g   ---> highlights all comments, including above ones (?!! is to ignore #!/usr/bin/env perl )
```

I'm currently struggling to join these two comments to achieve the above result. Ive tried using forward and reverse lookups but cant seem to get this right.Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are hoping to write a program that will remove comments from Perl code then I think you are wasting your time. You have to consider things like `$string =~ s#//#/#g` and `for my $i (0 .. $#array) { ... }`, and probably several others

Comment: If you are hoping to write a program that will remove comments from Perl code, that program has already been written. Use [`PPI`](http://metacpan.org/pod/PPI).

Comment: not sure why it was put on hold, the question was mainly about joining 2 statements, not just removing the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this simple method?

1. remove all substrings between double or single quotes first
2. extract out substring after a `#` by a simple regular expression cpature

Here is the test program for your sample input:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/['"][^'"]*['"]//g;
    if (m/#(.*)/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
"#dummy comment" asd asd
' abc # dummy comment'
abc #real comment
```

Comment: sorry to sound like a noob, but say if I already had my data stored in a single variable/string $str instead of a data file, how would i use the above while loop then. I tried it myself but just got an infinite loop. Thanks :D

Comment: @SimpsonDanny Then you could remove that `while` loop, using something like `$str =~ s/['"][^'"]*['"]//g; print "$1\n" if $str =~ m/#(.*)/;`

Comment: thanks, i think im heading in the right direction.